# SQL Between Statement using two Sub-queries that could return multiple values

Tags: sql, subquery, between

**Purpose**:  To perform alpha splits on work-lists based on roles assigned to a user.  The below logic works if the user only has ONE alpha split (ex. A-CZZZ), but I need the flexibility for some users to have multiple splits (ex. A-CZZZ AND T-ZZZZ).

**High Level**:

```
SELECT Name
FROM PatientDatabase
WHERE Name Between
   (SELECT UserRole.AlphaFrom
    FROM UserRole
    WHERE UserRole.HasRole = 1)
    AND
   (SELECT UserRole.AlphaThru
    FROM UserRole
    WHERE UserRole.HasRole = 1)
```

Potential Names in PatientDatabase:

```
ABC,PERSON
LMN,PERSON
XYZ,PERSON
```

Current User has two UserRoles (alpha splits):

```
A-CZZZ
T-ZZZZ
```

I want to return:

```
ABC,PERSON
XYZ,PERSON
```

I believe the subqueries may be necessary given the security-related logic below.

**INFO**:

```
-'Roledef->ReportingCategory1->Name' is the AlphaFrom
-'Roledef->ReportingCategory2->Name' is the AlphaThru
```

**Current Logic for alpha split that works when only one (or on the first split if more than one)**:

```
AND T.PatId->PatNm BETWEEN
    (SELECT E2.Roledef->ReportingCategory1->Name
    FROM SECURITYPLUS.USR S2, SecurityPlus.UsrETMRole E2,
    SecurityPlus.UsrETMApplication A2
    WHERE A2.USR = S2.USERNAME AND
    E2.USRETMAPPLICATION = A2.ID AND S2.Username = ? 
    AND E2.Roledef->Name ['Alpha')
    AND
    (SELECT E3.Roledef->ReportingCategory2->Name
    FROM SECURITYPLUS.USR S3, SecurityPlus.UsrETMRole E3,
    SecurityPlus.UsrETMApplication A3
    WHERE A3.USR = S3.USERNAME AND
    E3.USRETMAPPLICATION = A3.ID AND S3.Username = ?  
    AND E3.Roledef->Name ['Alpha')
```

**Entire SQL Logic for context**:

```
SELECT
T.Id,
T.PatId->Mrn,
T.PatId->PatNm,
T.Invoice,
T.Invoice->Fsc,
T.Stage->Name As Stage,
T.Status->Name As Status,
T.Invoice->InvBal,
T.ReviewDate,
T.HasNoteFlag

FROM
TaskManager.Task T

WHERE
T.TaskNm->Name = 'Insurance Followup'

AND T.Status IN (SELECT ID FROM Dict.ETMTaskStatus TS
                 WHERE StatusType NOT IN ('DELETED','DONE'))

AND T.Invoice->Fsc->EtmRole IN
    (SELECT E1.Roledef
    FROM SECURITYPLUS.USR S1, SecurityPlus.UsrETMRole E1,
    SecurityPlus.UsrETMApplication A1
    WHERE A1.USR = S1.USERNAME AND
    E1.USRETMAPPLICATION = A1.ID AND S1.Username = ?)

AND T.PatId->PatNm BETWEEN
    (SELECT E2.Roledef->ReportingCategory1->Name
    FROM SECURITYPLUS.USR S2, SecurityPlus.UsrETMRole E2,
    SecurityPlus.UsrETMApplication A2
    WHERE A2.USR = S2.USERNAME AND
    E2.USRETMAPPLICATION = A2.ID AND S2.Username = ? 
    AND E2.Roledef->Name ['Alpha')
    AND
    (SELECT E3.Roledef->ReportingCategory2->Name
    FROM SECURITYPLUS.USR S3, SecurityPlus.UsrETMRole E3,
    SecurityPlus.UsrETMApplication A3
    WHERE A3.USR = S3.USERNAME AND
    E3.USRETMAPPLICATION = A3.ID AND S3.Username = ?  
    AND E3.Roledef->Name ['Alpha')
```

**This next logic returns the table I need, but I cannot figure out how to get a between statement to work with this:**

```
SELECT E2.Roledef->ReportingCategory1->Name As AlphaFrom,
       E2.Roledef->ReportingCategory2->Name As AlphaThru
    FROM SECURITYPLUS.USR S2, SecurityPlus.UsrETMRole E2,
    SecurityPlus.UsrETMApplication A2
    WHERE A2.USR = S2.USERNAME AND
    E2.USRETMAPPLICATION = A2.ID AND S2.Username = ? 
    AND E2.Roledef->Name ['Alpha'
```

**Returns**:

```
AlphaFrom    AlphaThru
A            CZZZ
T            ZZZZ
```

I suspect I will have to abandon the sub-queries in order to accomplish this since attempts at joining them have failed, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: . . Complex SQL code is hard to follow.  Could you provide some examples of input data and the desired results?

Comment: @ypercube - It is based on Intersystems Cache version 5.something and used within a billing system.  The "->" drills thru to additional tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I tried to add a high level example at the top of the post.  It does not necessarily make sense but gives a clearer picture of what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

My eventual answer was to create a custom field in our Role dictionary, then create a Role for each letter of the alphabet and use an "IN" statement as opposed to a "BETWEEN".

Using the high level example:

```
SELECT Name
FROM PatientDatabase
WHERE LEFT(Name,1) In
   (SELECT UserRole.Alpha
    FROM UserRole
    WHERE UserRole.HasRole = 1)
```